# Rsyncing both ways while handling deletes

Tags: rsync

Right now, I am currently running rsync in two different ways:

```
rsync -r -avz --delete --progress -e "ssh -p 8443" root@<my_server>:~/app ~/Desktop/;
rsync -r -avz --progress -e "ssh -p 8443" ~/Desktop/app root@<my_server>:~/app/
```

Obviously the problem here is that if a file doesn't exist on the server, then it gets deleted locally. So if you created a file locally *after* it synchronized to the server, the first command will run and delete it again locally. If you switch the `--delete` option to the other command, then the reverse happens.

I've tried experimenting and researching this to do it a few different ways, but I cannot seem to come around to a way that synchronizes changes on both sides depending on what happened first.

An alternative that I saw was Unison, but I have errors with this as well when the version doesn't match between the client and the server.